# React Native init Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby, react-native

`which ruby`
outputs -> /Users/User/.rbenv/shims/ruby

`ruby -v`
outputs -> ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [x86_64-darwin21]

`which bundle`
outputs -> /Users/User/.rbenv/shims/bundle

`bundle -v`
outputs -> Bundler version 2.1.4

but the problem is that `npx react-native init MyProject`
outputs -> ✖ Installing Bundler
error Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch: Your Ruby version is 2.6.10, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.5

Answer (score 0):

What's likely happening is that `npx react-native init MyProject` is sub-shelling into Bash where you do not have rbenv configured. When it tries to run `ruby` from Bash it looks in `$PATH` and finds the default macOS version of Ruby -- 2.6.10 -- and errors out.

This is discussed thoroughly in the [react-native repo](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35053) where there are many solutions, but what it boils down to is `react-native init` is not finding the right version of Ruby, for whatever reason. You can bypass that by completing the failing part of the `init` process yourself with:

```bash
cd MyProject
bundle install
cd ios && bundle exec pod install
```

The longer version of the solution is to [configure rbenv for Bash](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#basic-git-checkout) as well, but this isn't necessary as you can likely use just the workaround above:

```bash
echo 'eval "$(~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv init - bash)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```