# Ruby 2.7 brew and Ruby 2.6 from os on machine... i only want 2.7

Tags: ios, ruby, macos, cocoapods

I am trying to get an iOS app working built via capacitorjs.

I have installed the lastest Ruby via Brew.

But now there seems to be a problem in that cocoapods keeps trying to use the old ruby (installed and shipped with the OS).

It was advised to update ruby and cocoa pods... but now 'pods install' is referencing ruby 2.6 instead of the new 2.7 version.

```
pod --version 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'ffi' (>= 1.15.0) among 81 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.6.0:/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1449:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1420:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1452:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1420:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1452:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1420:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1452:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1420:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:304:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:303:in `synchronize'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:303:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

When I run which ruby on cli is shows 2 versions:

```
which -a ruby
/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby@2.7/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

And when running ruby version is say 2.7:

```
ruby --version
ruby 2.7.7p221 (2022-11-24 revision 168ec2b1e5) [arm64-darwin22]
```

It is a confusing, but it feels like cocoapods is configured somewhere to use the old version and not the new?

Could anyone tell me how to get pods to use the new version installed?

I was expecting that installing ruby 2.7, exporting the path var and restarting the machine would have resolved the links, but no joy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74942677/3784008

Comment: For anyone hitting the same issue, the real answer is here https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10512

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10512) on GitHub.

Basically, the reason is cocoapods in the bin folder was not updated for whatever reason and referenced the system's 2.6 version of gem.

Removing this version of pod then allowed the OS to pickup the new version installed by brew.

You do not need to install or configure https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#basic-git-checkout